# Does being outdoors but in close proximity to someone make a difference in Covid-19 transmission?

Tags: covid-19, prevention, respiratory-system, non-pharmaceutical-interventions

In a recent [news article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-53994209) I've read that

> Outdoor haircuts were allowed in California from Tuesday, under new rules announced by the mayor, but indoor salons remain shut.

Is this kind of rule/recommendation based on substantial empirical evidence? Is doing/having the same kind of fairly close interaction between people but outdoors substantially less likely to spread Covid-19 (or respiratory diseases in general)?